# How to debug Java Server working for localhost but not public IP

Tags: java, unix, configuration, jersey, localhost

Noob question but I'm not sure where to look:

I'm running a Java Web App on a remote linux machine (Jersey RESTful API is the goal). The server successfully runs and can handle requests locally to localhost:8080/foobar but I cannot make requests to the various urls from anywhere else (For example, my laptop through a browser).

This is a simple problem I've have many times but have no idea what terms to search on google or where to look for help debugging the problem, so any leads or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Further details:
Project is code added to a Maven2 generated archetype of a Jersey Service

Comment: Do you have the port forwarding set up correctly from your router?

Comment: I want to say yes but, I'm not sure -- how would I check?

Comment: Open your router page. Port forward the traffic from your router to the IP Address of the local machine that is hosting the web server.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely caused by firewalling on the server or in front of the internal network your server is running on.  Talk to your network administrators about opening a hole for port 8080, or consider using a reverse proxy on port 80 (if open) to forward requests to port 8080.   See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy if you are not familiar with the idea of a reverse proxy or load balancers.

Answer (score 0):

Change the localhost entry in your "/etc/hosts" file, with the network configs, and if server is tomcat, edit the $CATALINA_HOME/conf/server.xml to add IP the relevant `<Connector>` element.

**Make sure you have better idea handling /etc/hosts**